# How can I run multiple python scripts one after another?

Tags: python

How can I run multiple python scripts one after another? At the moment I run one like so python script1.py.

I've tried python script1.py script2.py and that doesn't work: only the first script is run. Also, I've tried using a single file like this;

```
import script1
import script2

python script1.py
python script2.py
```

However this doesn't work either.

Also i need HTML output at the end of execution..How can i achieve that?

Comment: `python script1.py && python script2.py ` ?

Comment: Please consider editing [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50797580/how-to-get-the-test-output-of-multiple-python-file-as-a-html-output-at-the-end-o) rather than posting a new one. I know it's tempting to start over when your first attempt doesn't get much positive attention, but it's best to stick to one post, to reduce clutter on the site :-)

Comment: @Rakesh beat me to it but yes && for "run script2 if script1 passes" and & for "run script2 even if script1 fails"

Comment: Thanks Rakesh for the response..If i have more than 100 of files then how should i maintain that?

Comment: You have 100 python scripts in a folder to execute?

Comment: Yes Rakesh, I have rather 1500 scripts to execute..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse output of `find` command and use `xargs`, running this in the same folder of your python files

```
find . -name '*.py' -maxdepth 1 | xargs python
```

in the case you mentioned of hundreds of `.py` files. 
Other option you may consider is to create an additional `.py` file to call your other `.py` files